# Google Apps Script Properties Quota Clarification

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

Hoping to get some clarification on what Google describes as the quotas for Google Apps Script Properties. The quotas and limits are found here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

The page lists 50,000 writes to Properties per day. I believe that is for each user. Is that for all of that user's Add-ons? So, in theory, my Add-on would be sharing the user's Property write quota with all of their other Add-ons?

The other question I had was with Properties total storage. The page lists a limit of 500 kb/property store. What's considered a Property Store? Does that mean each Add-on has a single Property Store and can only hold 500kB of Properties of any kind? Or, does it mean that each Add-on has a Property Store for User Properties, another for Document Properties, and another for Script Properties - each with the 500kB limit?

Or, is there another definition of a Property store in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard from Google that the write limit is per user, but also very hard to reach.

And, Property Stores are by script. So, Document Properties have a maximum capacity of 500kB for each Document per script.

Answer (score 5):

Properties stores are per script, so a script has 1 property store, plus unlimited number of user stores .. one for each new person that uses the script, and one for each script that the document touches.

The quotas apply individually to each store.

- The user property store for script A for user X, is a different store that for script B, user X.
- the script property store for script A, is the same one for both user X and user Y.
- the document store for script A, document D, is a different one than script A, document E
- the document store for Script A, document D is the same for all users.

Since libraries are also separate scripts, they also have their own stores.